# How to show these two id at the same time by onclick?

Tags: javascript

I have these html code:

```
<div id="overlay" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed; background-color: bisque; z-index: 2; opacity: 0.5; top: 0; display: none"></div>

<div id="form" style="display: none; z-index: 3">

<div class="tooltip" onclick="show('form')" style="cursor: pointer;"><a><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><span class="tooltiptext">Offer Suggestions</span></div>
```

And a function:

```
function show(target){
    document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'block';
}

function hide(target){
    document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'none';
};
```

When I click on `.tooltip`, only the `#form` appears.

What can I do to make `#overlay` and `#form` appear at the same time on a click base on this function?

This is my first post, sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: why dont you write code to display both element inside the show function itself

Comment: change the onclick to `show('form', 'overlay')` and change the function to `function show(target, target1){
document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById(target1).style.display = 'block';
}`

Comment: #Deepsorry, i am new to script
#Kevin Kloet, thank you, i have tried but only the form appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing in the argument as an Id, just hard code the ids into your functions:

```js
function show(){ // remove target var from function
    document.getElementById('form').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'block';
}

function hide(){
    document.getElementById('form').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'none';
};
```

then change your onclick to not have the target too:

```
<div class="tooltip" onclick="show()" style="cursor: pointer;"><a><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><span class="tooltiptext">Offer Suggestions</span></div>
```

Comment: I dont know what problem i am encoutering, I've tried your code, but only the form appears, is there any problem with my css?